# GAE / GTM: Error response [13] during switch to production

Tags: google-app-engine, google-tag-manager

I would like to implement the Google Tag Manager as a server-side processing container via GAE (default). I’ve done this for other projects before.

However, when I switch the configuration to production, I get the following error message after executing the shell script provided for this purpose:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
```

The error code doesn't tell me anything and I haven’t found any documentation about it. Just in a different context.

For the sake of completeness, the shell script:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://googletagmanager.com/static/serverjs/setup.sh)"
```

I’ running this operation as the owner (IAM role).

Thanks!

Comment: What does the logs in GCP for App Engine say?

Comment: Hey. The last entry before the process is aborted is a notice from appengine.googleapis.com. Normally the build process should start afterwards. There is no further error message :(

Comment: In a log file I've found this:

File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 182, in IsDone
    raise OperationError(requests.ExtractErrorMessage(
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
2022-02-24 21:31:25,893 ERROR    root            (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Error 13 seems to be a generic error message (but often tied to permissions issues according to previous threads). You can try both options from the troubleshooting guide in the [App Engine guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/script-user-guide#troubleshoot_production_deployment_timeouts) for Google Tag Manager container. You first have to confirm if both the App Engine and Compute Engine default service accounts have the `Editor` role:

This is seen inside **IAM & Admin -> IAM -> Roles -> Editor**:

`<project_number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
`<project_name>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

If that’s as it should be, you also need to review your Compute Engine API quotas, which is done in  **IAM & Admin -> Quotas** and then by filtering for `Compute Engine API`.

I was able to deploy a Google Tag Manager container to App Engine using the script and procedure shown [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/script-user-guide#troubleshoot_production_deployment_timeouts), and I was also able to swap between both testing and production settings without running into any error. An additional thing you can include here give you a better answer is the `app.yaml` file generated by the GTM script, which you can find in **App Engine -> Versions -> Config Column(View)**. Just make sure to **not include any sensitive data**.

These are my installed versions of the `gcloud` CLI:

```
Google Cloud SDK 373.0.0
alpha 2022.02.11
beta 2022.02.11
bq 2.0.73
bundled-python3-unix 3.8.11
core 2022.02.11
gsutil 5.6
```

Comment: @Niko were you able to test if these steps helped in deploying your GTM container?